# Is there a specific word for hemocyanic blood?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to be able to use a word specifically meaning the blue blood -- having hemocyanin rather than hemoglobin -- that, for example, an octopus has.  I have been unable to find one using the internet.  Does any such word exist?

Comment: See [Blood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood) on Wikpedia, under para-3. "Vertebrate blood is bright red when its hemoglobin is oxygenated. Some animals, such as **crustaceans** and **mollusks**, use **hemocyanin** to carry oxygen, instead of hemoglobin. Insects and some mollusks use a fluid called **hemolymph** instead of blood, the difference being that hemolymph is not contained in a closed circulatory system. In most insects, this 'blood' does not contain oxygen-carrying molecules such as hemoglobin[.]"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a matter of fact, it's called [hemolymph/haemolymph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemolymph).